# YellowFin Error : Oh no! An error occurred saving your details to the database

Tags: database

I'm using Yellowfin 9.8, I'm trying to import some user using CSV format then I receive an error message : "Oh no! An error occurred saving your details to the database". Is my format correct??

CSV:

[image]